# Simple array (image extension wildcard) works locally but not online

Tags: php

I started out with a simple script that displays an image at the top of each page on my site. I then decided to modify it so that images will display regardless of their extensions. (Most of the images are jpg's, but there are a few png's and gif's, too.)

My script works fine locally, but not online. Online, it only displays jpg's. If I change the very first line of code so that the last extension in the array is png, then it only displays png's.

```
$extensions =  array('gif', 'png', 'jpg');

switch(PHP_OS)
{
 case 'Linux':
 $Root = '/public_html/symbols';
 break;
 default:
 $Root = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gs';
 break;
}

foreach($extensions as $extension) {
  $file =  '/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.''.$Multi .'.'.$extension;
  if(file_exists($Root.$file)) {
  // echo '<img src="'.$file.'">';
  break;
 }
}

// This switch simply styles images that have captions. The important thing is the image path, including $extension. Why does it work locally but not online?

switch($ImgCaption)
{
 case '':
 $TopImg = '<div><img src="/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.''.$Multi.'.'.$extension.'" alt="'.$MyName.' '.$DesigGen.'"></div>';
 break;
 default:
 $TopImg = '<div><img src="/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.''.$Multi.'.'.$extension.'" alt="'.$MyName.' '.$DesigGen.'">
 <div class="Txt">'.$ImgCaption.'</div></div>';
 break;  
}

echo $TopImg;
```

**EDIT:**

I tried Dagon's suggestion, as follows:

```
foreach    (glob("'/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.'' .$Multi.'.'.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename);

$TopImg = '<img src="'.$filename.'">';
```

I get the error message "undefined variable." I must be implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: let me guess, local=windows =case insensitive. remote=*nix -case Sensitive ?

Comment: That was one of my first guesses. But if that was the problem, why would the script work at all? I would expect it to 1) display images regardless of extension or 2) display no images at all. Or am I missing something?

Comment: are the file extension of the online files all lower case?

Comment: P.S. I also wondered if it might have to do with my tinkering with Apache to default all the URL's to lower case and replace underscores with dashes (new-hampshire vs New_Hampshire). But, again, if that was a problem, wouldn't it kill ALL the images?

Comment: side note looping extentions looking for a file seems like an odd apporach

Comment: I'm open for better ideas. ;) In fact, I think all I need is some sort of image extension wildcard that I can just insert in my script. I thought that would be a very simple proposition, but I've Google'd for help and found nothing that worked for me.

Comment: `foreach (glob("'/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.''.$Multi .'.'.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {)`

Comment: I edited my original post, adding the glob script. I had to change it a big to fix a syntax error. But I think I'm making a simple mistake regarding echoing $filename.

Answer (score 0):

The code in foreach loop can get you to unexpected results if the file does not exist in any extension (always get the last extension at the end of foreach)

```
 $ext="";  
 foreach($extensions as $extension) {
     $file =  '/images/sections/world/top/'.$DesigGen.'/'.$ImgParent.'/'.$MyID2.''.$Multi .'.'.$extension;
     if(file_exists($Root.$file)) {
          // only if file exists assign extension
          $ext=$extension;
          break;
     }
 }
 if ($ext==""){
       //...
   }
```

I think the *$Root* variable could be wrong for the online site, leading to fail the file_exists() check.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a subdomain. Maybe I can fix it by playing around with the online root value.